# RPM: files created in %post are lost during upgrade

Tags: yum, rpm, dnf

In my `.spec` file I create directory and touch a file in in during `%post` stage:

```
%post
mkdir -p %{sharedstatedir}/my_app
touch %{sharedstatedir}/my_app/my_app_file.txt
```

However during `dnf upgrade my_app` `/var/lib/my_app` and its contents are deleted and don't get re-created again. I think I could make `%{sharedstatedir}/my_app` and `%{sharedstatedir}/my_app/my_app_file.txt` part of the package, i.e. add them in `%files` section, but is there another way, just re-create the files in `%post` for example? I don't really care if contents of my_app_file.txt is lost, it serves as temporary storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty file, declare that an installation object with the [`%config`](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejw35/docs/rpm_config.html) property, so that its content remains unchanged if it changed on disk before  you'd do an update.

Honestly, though: Don't abuse the `%config` command or run code in `%post` to create mutable shared state files (which end up in /var/lib); my guess is that rpmlint will complain about what you intend to do, and it will *notice* it, at least when you use `%config`. A temporary file should be created by the software itself, when it's not there! So, just `%file`-create the directory `%{sharedstatedir}/my_app`, and patch the software to create the file if it's not there. Ideally, the path to the file should be configurable, so that admins can choose to put it e.g. on a faster or less reliable storage.

Comment: Declaring `my_app/my_app_file.txt` as `%config` is not what I need - this way it rather won't be deleted on uninstall, however I need it to be completely removed.

Comment: yeah, then see my "honestly, though" section.